# Loading a Dictionary from MySQL

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possiable to load a Classic ASP Dictionary from a MySQL Query? If so could you please show me how I could do it or point me in the direction to do it? Thanks!

Resources: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_dictionary.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is you just need to query you MySql DB and then use a loop to insert all the records to your dictionary.

I'm using JSctip ASP because that is the example i have but it's very easy to transform it to VB just use the substitute  objects.

```
var Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
var RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
var ConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server="+PDServer+";Database="+PDDB+"; Uid="+PDUser+";Pwd="+PDPass+";"
Conn.open(ConnString)

var sqlStr = ""
sqlStr+="SELECT * "
sqlStr+="FROM [Table] "
sqlStr+="WHERE [CONDITION]"


RS = Conn.execute(sqlStr)

while (!RS.EOF)
{
    //myDictionary.add(key,value)   
}
Conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, don't worry about the example. I can query the db in to an array then loop through and stuff up the dictionary. I was just wondering if there was something like dictionary = rs.getrows or something where it would populate with the field names and data per row. Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem. but Note that if you use that a lot you would probably want to make a generic procedure that does that exact thing. It will recive a Recordset and return a dictionary according to a key vlue that will be given by column names.

Comment: Okay, well my I have a permissions table that handles user permissions so I was going to dump that in the dictionary and use the dictionary throughout the site to check if a user has permission. That way I don't have to keep ping the db to check. And because there keys I can call a key and check it for a pass/fail. Thanks again!!!